# Issues while developing vertical menu bar

Tags: menu, submenu

I had made a vertical menu bar in project by using the following link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/how_to_create_a_vertical_left_hand_menu

but now the issue is vertical menu does not provide sub menu and even if I add code for sub category i.e submenu also making required changes in css it does not work.
Secondly, the vertical menu bar is in home page so user cannot view it throughout while browsing so please help me where the changes is to be done (`header.phtml` or `navigation.phtml` or `left.phtml` or `left_vert.phtml` in `page.xml`).

Answer (score 1):

easy solution:

write `$this->drawItem($_category,4)` instead.

The second argument tells how deep the categories should get listed. Default is 0, which explains your problem.